# Discord.py Bot Kick/DM Command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm learning how to create a discord bot using python and I'm having trouble with this one command. What I'm trying to do is kick a specific user and then dm them a invite back to the discord server using the bot. It is a silly idea but I really want to make it work.

I specifically am having trouble with is how to kick a specific user (with user ID) and then DM that user.

Thanks!

Here the code:

```
if message.content == '!kickjohn':
    if "527290609166188554" in [role.id for role in message.author.roles]:
        <KICK JOHN COMMAND>
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "_**Bye Bye John!**_")
        await client.send_message(<JOHN>, 'https://discord.gg/XXXXXXX')
    else:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "sorry you can't do that")
```

The goal of this is that if someone of the appropriate role types `!kickjohn` a specific discord user id (`john`) gets kicked and the bot automatically dm's john an invite to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a command to make it easier, if you have an `on_message` function add `await bot.process_commands(message)` like so

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

```py
@commands.has_role("role_name_here")#makes it so that only works with specific role
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def kick(msg,user:discord.Member): #this converts the member you mention into a usuer object, you can also do it by user id or server nickname if you don't want to mention them
    """[Create an invite code then kicks the user]
    """
    code=await bot.create_invite(msg.message.channel) #create the invite code
    await bot.send_message(user,f'{code}') #Send the invite code first because you must have common server to send message to user
    await bot.kick(user) #kick the user
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have put this into my code but i don't really know how to use it. What would i have to type to actually make it work? sorry lol

Comment: Assuming that the bot prefix is `.` you  can use the following methods`.kick @Cheng Yue`, `.kick Cheng Yue` or by user's ID `.kick 19234819283`

Answer (score 0):

just replace all the <> with what you want to be in them

```
    @client.command(pass_context=True)
    async def kick(ctx, user: discord.Member):
        if "527290609166188554" in [role.id for role in ctx.message.author.roles]:
            await client.send_message(user, "<message><link>")
            await client.kick(user)
            await client.say("{} Just got Kicked".format(user.name))
        else:
            await client.say("<access denied because of improper role message>")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
@client.command(description="kicks a user with specific reason (only admins)") #kick
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kick (ctx, member:discord.User=None, reason =None):
 try:
    if (reason == None):
        await ctx.channel.send("You  have to specify a reason!")
        return
    if (member == ctx.message.author or member == None):
        await ctx.send("""You cannot kick yourself!""") 

    message = f"You have been kicked from {ctx.guild.name} for {reason}"
    await member.send(message)
    await ctx.guild.kick(member, reason=reason)
    print(member)
    print(reason)
    await ctx.channel.send(f"{member} is kicked!")
 except:
    await ctx.send(f"Error kicking user {member} (cannot kick owner or bot)")
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a working and perfect one for you

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", case_insensitive=True)
token = "XXXXyyyyZzZz:AAAAAbbbbbCCCCCddddd"

@bot.command()
async def kick(ctx, member:discord.Member):
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} has been kicked from this server by {ctx.author.mention}")
    dm = await member.create_dm()
    server_name = "name of your server"
    invite_link = "put_link_here"
    await member.kick()
    await dm.send(f"You got kicked out of the server {server_name},\nYou can join again - {invite_link}")

bot.run(token)
```

Now when you will use - `!kick @jhon`
the bot will kick jhon and send him a dm with an invite link ....